# How the indentation works in case of switch case in Java?

Tags: java

```
switch (a){
            case 'B':
                case 'C':
                    System.out.println("nothing");
        }


So here in the above case if I enter B then it prints nothing and same goes for entering C
Bt if viewed like if-statement then it should be smthing like



if (a == 'B') {
                if (a == 'C'){
                    System.out.println("nothing");
                }
            }
```

So here on entering B and C and storing in variable a it should not print anything as the statement inside C can only be printed when a will equal to B and C which is not possible

Comment: Unlike Python, indentation does not really matter in the JLS (Java Language Specification).  You could even have all your code on a single line.

Comment: ...when a will equal to B ***OR*** C...

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 2):

Just as an FYI, it's best to print something, usually "foo": or "bar" for generic questions, rather than the string "nothing." The statement `it prints nothing` is easily interpreted to mean there is no output, rather than that the output is the string "nothing"

When using a switch, view the `case` keyword not like an if-else statement, but rather an entry point into the code block. When combined with the `break` keyword you get if-else semantics.

Consider the following

```
        switch (a) {
            case 'B':
                System.out.println("foo");
            case 'C':
                System.out.println("bar");
        }
```

Here for B you get `foo\nbar`. For case C you only get `bar`. If we include break statements...

```
        switch (a) {
            case 'B':
                System.out.println("foo");
                break;
            case 'C':
                System.out.println("bar");
                break;
        }
```

We get if-else semantics. If we want nested if else semantics then we'd need a switch within a switch...

```
        switch (someVar.getFoo()) {
            case A:
                //do something
                switch(someVar.getBar()) {
                    case X:
                        //continue doing something...
                        break
                }
                break;
            case B:
                //do something else...
                break;
        }
```